# Flask rate limiting counting false request

Tags: flask, rate-limiting

This is my function where I am using multiple rate limiter

```
@core.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_or_api_token_required
@user_limiter.limit("1/minute")
@global_limiter.limit("2/minute")
def test():
    logger.info('app test route hit')
    return 'Congratulations! Your core-app test route is running!'
```

and this is my limiter setup

```
global_limiter = Limiter(
    key_func=lambda: "global",
    app=app,
    default_limits=["2/hour"],
    # storage_uri="memory://",
    storage_uri="redis://localhost:6379",
    storage_options={"socket_connect_timeout": 30},
    strategy="fixed-window",
)

user_limiter = Limiter(
    key_func=get_user_id,
    app=app,
    default_limits=["1/hour"],
    storage_uri="redis://localhost:6379",
    storage_options={"socket_connect_timeout": 30},
    strategy="fixed-window",
)
```

so I want is if the @user_limiter.limit("1/minute") is success then goes to the @global_limiter.limit("2/minute") else not. because right now if the @user_limiter.limit("1/minute") get 429 response it also goes and count on the global limiter same goes for if @global_limiter.limit("2/minute") is already done and one user try it out 1 time then his user rate limiter also gone but since he wasn't able to use it he just get to see too many requests 2 per minute in the response but still, his 1 request counted for the false call